# App crashes in debug mode(iOS) but works fine in test flight and android

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am experieincing a weird issue where my app crashes only in debug mode in iOS in both simulator and device, where as it works absolutely fine in testflight and android(both debug and release).

It doesnt however crash in every screen. There are certain screens where it crashes. Code in those screens seem absolutely normal, which is how other screens have been written.

[image]

crash log saysterminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally a view controller <UIViewController: 0x1065585c0> that is already being presented by <UIViewController: 0x10641b430>.'

Would really appreciate some help, been stuck on this since a week

Comment: Are you showing the modal view ?

Comment: In one of the screen I was showing the modal... but even if I comment out the modal part it shows the error

Comment: what operation you are performing that leads to the crash ?

Comment: Its a simple flatlist listing whose onpress opens inapp browser(using react-native-inappbrowser-reborn). Whenever this screen renders it crashes. Same inapp browser has been used in a different screen where it is behaving absolutely fine.

Comment: Are you using any pickers like for image or video or for something else or you might showing the modal view ?

Comment: No there aren't any modal view in that specific screen or in any component related to that screen. However a picker has been used inside a drawer which exists in the same screen. But the same drawer is also used in multiple other screens where they are working fine.

Comment: Can you please show the piece of code that causing the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234805/discussion-between-sjonchhe-and-jignesh-mayani).

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix for it. It was related to font file not recognized by the system